Mock axios request methods with native node:test test runner
This question has been asked and answered for sinon, jest, and others, but I'm trying and failing to get axios mocks set up using Node's native node:test test runner.
Here's generally what I'm doing:
test.spec.ts
import axios from 'axios';
import { describe, test, mock, beforeEach, assert } from 'node:test';
import assert from 'node:assert/strict';
import { MyClass } from 'MyClass.ts';

const AxiosMock = {
  get: async (url: string) => {
    if (url.startsWith('https://www.my.url')) {
      return Promise.resolve({
        'field': 'value'
      });
    }

    return Promise.reject();
  }
};

describe('axios mock test suite', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mock.restoreAll();

    mock.method(axios, 'get', AxiosMock.get);
  });

  test('axios mock test', () => {
    const o = new MyClass();
    o.doTheThingThatCallsAxios();

    assert( #stuff );
  });
});

MyClass.ts
import axios from 'axios';

export class MyClass {
  public doTheThingThatCallsAxios() => {
    return axios.get('https://www.my.url');
  }
}

The problem is just that the method isn't mocked, and it attempts to make the request. I assume that it's because the axios is static, and the instances I import in MyClass and in the test class are distinct...
Any help here?

I have not tried myself but if it is the static part you could try something like:
import axios from 'axios';

export class MyClass {
    public doTheThingThatCallsAxios() => {
        const http = axios.create();
        return http.get('https://www.my.url');
    }
}

